# Best method for Node.JS forking?

Tags: node.js

I'm writing a trajectory predictor in Node.JS. You may think it's a funny language to write one in, but it's actually working great. Now, I want to be able to start the predictor from a web interface in Node.JS.

The actual predictor process takes about 5 minutes to run. So to spawn it from the Node web process, I don't want the web process waiting for the child process to finish. What is the best method of forking, in Node.JS, to allow for spawning and releasing a process like this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in `child_process` node module:  http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: If called from Node as a webserver, would this detach the process so that the web process could continue to work normally?

Comment: Yes, it would.  It being node, I don't think there even is a legitimate way to start a child process that your webserver process would block on.